# Html table, make one row larger

Tags: html

I'm not very familiar with HTML, so excuse me if this is something simple, but I couldn't figure it out from googling. Anyway, the problem i'm having can be illustrated by this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>lots of words blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>word</td>
            <td>word</td>
            <td>word</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way that rather then have the first column be stretched, that just that first cell gets bigger? Theres only one cell in the first row, so theres alot of empty space. I'd like the cell to expand to fit the row, but instead it either stretches the whole column, or stretches vertically. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 7):

Use the colspan attribute to tell it to cover multiple columns, so in your case the `td` on your first row would be `<td colspan="3">`

Answer (score 5):

Set `colspan="3"` on the first `<td>` element.

Like this: `<td colspan="3">`.

The colspan value is how many columns do you want it to take up.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your rows should have the same number of columns. In this case, you can explicitly tell your large cell to span all of the columns, like this:

```
<tr> <td colspan="3">lots of words blah blah  </td>  </tr>
```

Comment: Not every row needs to be the same number of columns.  Gaps at the end are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the width attribute to the element you want to change.